# PHP/MySQL User Authentication Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I am using the following code from a book that is explaining how to do database authentication via PHP however I can not get it to work.  I continuously get the login prompt and am never allowed into my application.  The only thing I modified is the "realm" and field names in order to match up with my database.

Database configuration and connection scripts are external and not included below but I know they are correct as I have no problem inserting or selecting data from my database.

Also, I know mysql is deprecated but I am working on a quick project that will be upgraded once I have time to learn the newer code.  Please for now, respond based on mysql in that respect.

Finally this is a very small personal project and I know there are a lot of security errors...that is why I am learning.  For now, I am starting with the basics and just trying to get the code to work and then next I plan to learn sessions, encryption, etc.

Please go easy on me :) Thanks

```
<?php

require_once 'database_connection.php';

if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ||
    !isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="The Social Site"');
  exit("You need a valid username and password to be here. " .
       "Move along, nothing to see.");
}

// Look up the user-provided credentials
$query = sprintf("SELECT user_id, username FROM fbo_users" .
    "WHERE username = '%s' AND " .
    "       password = '%s';",
            mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])),
    mysql_real_escape_string(
        crypt(trim($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']), 
            $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])));

$results = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($results) == 1) {
  $result = mysql_fetch_array($results);
  $current_user_id = $result['user_id'];
  $current_username = $result['username'];
} else {
  header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
  header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="FBOtracker"');
  exit("You need a valid username and password to be here. " .
       "Move along, nothing to see.");
}

?>
```

Comment: `echo $query` and try to run it manually using phpMyAdmin, command line MySQL prompt or similar. Does it work? **If it does:** inpsect your PHP code to find out the issue. **If it doesn't:** edit your question to include the error message you're getting.

Comment: Is the problem with the PHP authentication rather than MySQL? I've never used this method of authentication (10+ years of PHP, and it's new to me), so why not try an HTML form and post variables and see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: Alternatively, is your encrypted username/password encrypted the same way as the data in the database? If it isn't it'll never work. Try echoing your SQL to see if what is being generated is actually what you want.

Comment: And here I went and changed my name to `Fred -ii-` after seeing another some time back. How many Fred's are there on SO? lol @fred2

Comment: echo $query doesn't do anything.  I am basically stuck inside the if statement.  I enter known database credentials and it continues to show the login prompt and doesn't allow access to the page I am protecting.  I am using "The Missing Manual" as my learning guide.

Comment: Apologies if this is a stupid question, but you are using the credential STORED in the database and not the username/password used to connect to MySQL, right? Establish which IF statement you are locked in ... are you getting booted out before the check on the DB, or after the DB check, when it redirects you to the 2nd IF? If you are getting booted by the first one, then it suggests that $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] or $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] are not set, and you need to find out why.

Comment: So ... try echoing $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] or $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] right at the start of the file, and see what it says.

Comment: Yes I am using stored credentials and NOT the database info.  I couldn't figure it out and found another solution that appears to be working...it just wasn't as much of a learning process as I was hoping for.